# Assembly. hybrid programm. "Divide error" and I don't divide anything

Tags: assembly, hybrid

I need to make a hyrid programm using c++ and assembly. Main function is written in c++. Function written in assembly adds float array elements. I had no problem to do it using intiger numbers but it looks much different using float point numbers.

Here is code:

```
PROC fun

    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    push cx
    push esi
    push ebx

         mov cx, word ptr [bp+12] ; array size
         mov [bp-8], ecx
         mov esi, dword ptr [bp+8] ; array
         mov ebx, 0 


        fld dword ptr [ebx]
p:  
        fld  dword ptr [esi]
        fadd 
        add esi, byte ptr 8
        loop p


        fst dword ptr [eax]

        pop esi
        pop cx
        pop ebx
        mov sp, bp
        pop bp

ret
ENDP
```

The problem is that if I run my programm it returns "Divide error" and I don't use any division :| Can somebody help me?

Comment: `mov ebx, 0` / `fld dword ptr [ebx]` what were you expecting that to do?

Comment: And why are you mixing 16 and 32-bit registers in your addresses? (e.g. `[bp+12]` vs `[esi]`)

Comment: hm I was trying here to strat adding elements. I meant 0+tab[0]

Comment: `tab[0]`? What's `tab`?

Comment: @Ayaka Instead of guessing, why not write the C++ code to add the floating point numbers, and see what the actual generated assembly code looks like.  Then work from there.

Comment: array name in c++ is tab

Comment: Did you take a 16-bit code example and hope this would work in 32-bit code?

Comment: If you "had no problem to do it using integer numbers", it probably best that you show us that particular version. Hopefully we can work from there.

Comment: @Ayaka: my point was that you say, "I meant 0+tab[0]" but there's no mention of `tab` in the posted code.  You need the code you post in the question to be the actual code you're having a problem with - if it's not, then fix it. Also the code should be enough for people to be able to understand the problem (in this case that might mean you should post the code that calls your assembly function). On the other hand, you don't just want to dump a wall of code that makes the problem difficult to see.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how the caller sets things up, this is hard to say.  However your best bet is to debug your way through this code, single-stepping, while verifying correct operation, to see exactly where you went wrong.  Also, the reference to `[bp - 8]` appears incorrect to me, and if your stack handling is wrong, a divide by zero could be caused by returning on a corrupted stack.  When assembler go awry, the messages from the other code around it are seldom meaningful.  You should expect this and always single-step through new assembler to observe and assess its initial behavior.